# Can not find JDK and Maven Configuration in Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I'm new to Jenkins and I am trying to configure my JDK and Maven home locations in Manage Jenkins > Configure, but I do not see those sections in the page. How do how make them visible?

Jenkins - Configure System
[image]

Answer (score 10):

The JDKs and Maven are managed and specified under "Manage Jenkins" -> "Global Tool Configuration" -> "JDK installations" and "Maven Installations"

Answer (score 3):

**On Jenkins 2.46 & up:**

Go to Manage Jenkins > Global Tool Configuration.

On that page, you can individually add the JDK and Maven paths by clicking on ***JDK installations...*** and ***Maven installations...*** buttons respectively.

Answer (score 1):

In: Manage Jenkins > Global Tool Configuration, 
find JDK

1. To install local JDK files, uncheck "Install automatically", then you can paste your local file location in JAVA_HOME
2. To download automatically, choose your option from Add Installer

I had tried both method, however only first one works for me. Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Search JDK and Maven inside the config page, you will find the place.

[Example to config the jdk](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/jenkins-the-definitive/9781449311155/ch04s05.html)

[Example to config the maven](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jenkins/jenkins_maven_setup.htm)

Comment: I actually see it in Global Tool Configuration. And my build ran successfully anyway - I didn't have to set the JDK & Maven locations.

Comment: First link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

The JDKs and Maven are managed and specified under "Manage Jenkins" -> "Global Tool Configuration" -> "JDK installations" and "Maven Installations" :- this worked as it helps in providing the required jdk version using the dropdown option and once we start to build any project, the jenkin will automatically download the jdk and the compilation error will not appear.

Answer (score 0):

JDK and Maven configurations can be setup in Jenkins using, Manage Jenkins -> Global tool configurations.